# Connecting to WIFI using esp8266

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, arduino-ide, wifi, esp8266

This is my code. I am tring to make a connection to my wifi through esp8266.

```
#define DST_IP "192.168.1.5" // my IP
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(0, 1);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  mySerial.begin(115200);
  while (! Serial); // Wait until Serial is ready - Leonardo
  Serial.println("AT+RST");
  delay(4000);
  Serial.println("AT+CWJAP=\"Ahmed\",\"12341234Aass\"");
  delay(4000);
  if (Serial.find("OK") )
  {
    Serial.println("1");
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("0");
  }
}

void loop()
{

}
```

This is the result of my code.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
SoftwareSerial mySerial(0, 1);
```

try changing **pin0** and **pin1** with some other pins. (lets say with **pin2** & **pin3**)

**pin0** and **pin1** are used by default **Serial**.

Comment: but **pin0** and **pin1** are my **RX** and **TX** .. is it true to work with any **pin** ?

Comment: yeh,  **pin0** and **pin1** are your **RX** and **TX**. **BUT** they are so, only when you are using **Serial**. In above mentioned line of code you are initializing another serial, **mySeial**, to use same pins as **Serial** which is the cause of error.

Comment: Thanks for replying **BUT** actually I use **mySeial** in nothing. So I removed it and still same error!

Comment: The point is that these pins are already used for the connection to the USB serial device proxying for the host PC.  You need to connect the ESP8266 to different pins, not to these.

Comment: Okay. I have set `SoftwareSerial mySerial(0, 1);` To `SoftwareSerial mySerial(2, 3);` But it always return 0 in the result which means it can not connect to the network.